# Firefox crashing inside docker container

Tags: docker, firefox, x11

Trying to launch firefox from the docker container with X window forwarding. It crashes every time.

- Firefox version container - Mozilla Firefox 60.8.0
- Host os firefox version - Mozilla Firefox 78.4.0esr
- OS - Suse linux (SLES 15 SP2)

**When I start the container with option --ipc= host it works fine. I am able to open the browser from the container. But this approach degrades the container isolation and security.**

Firefox Crash report trace -

```
(firefox:29957): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'firefox' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 520 error_code 2 request_code 130 (unknown) minor_code 3)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 30085
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
./runbrowser.sh: line 43: 29957 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped)
```

This is my Docker file

```
FROM hc-us-east-aws-artifactory.cloud.abc.com/docker-prod/gui-apps:0.6
WORKDIR /usr/g/applications//service
COPY ./service/target/rcp-rest-1.8.5.jar ./plat/rcp-rest.jar
COPY ./packageRPM/scripts/common ./scripts
COPY ./packageRPM/scripts/container ./scripts
COPY ./packageRPM/config ./config
RUN chmod -R 777 ./scripts
EXPOSE 8217
ENV DISPLAY=:0.0
USER myuser
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/usr/g/applications/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is the docker startup script

```
docker run --rm  \
         --name my-service \
         -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw \
         -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime \
         -e TZ=`ls -la /etc/localtime | cut -d/ -f7-9` \
         -e spring_profiles_active=Prod \
         --network="host" \
         --pid=host \
         local/my-service:latest
```

Please suggest if any other alternative.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, post your docker file.

Comment: added. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Should it be `ENV DISPLAY=:0` instead? Or just add `-e DISPLAY` to your `docker run` command